# reportlab issue with wrapOn

Tags: python, reportlab

I have an unexpected error using drawOn.
In this portion of my code, it works fine and generates the table:

```
r_table_02    = data_dict[value][202]
pdf_table_02  = Table(r_table_02, 0.75*inch, 0.40*inch)
pdf_table_02.setStyle(tblstyle)
h,w           = pdf_table_02.wrapOn(can, 0,0)
pdf_table_02.drawOn(can, 150,250)
```

But when running this part of the code, it generates an error:

```
r_table_03 = data_dict[value][203]
pdf_table_03 = Table(r_table_03, 0.75* inch, 0.40* inch)
pdf_table_03.setStyle(tblstyle)
h,w = pdf_table_03.wrapOn(can,0,0)
pdf_table_03.drawOn(can,100,450)  <<< this line generates the error.
```

Python protests:

```
Python Error Info: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'wrapOn'
```

both section of the code are pretty much the same.

Can anyone advise what could be wrong?